# calculating integral image(summed area table) for a pixel

Tags: image, integral

In the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_image) ,the formula for integral image (summed area table) is given as [image].

Why the negative fourth term? I got a bit confused by this ..Can someone illustrate with an example?

Answer (score 3):

The three integrals I(m, n) represent the entire area from (0, 0) to and including index (m, n). By adding the two integrals I(x-1, y) and I(x, y-1), the area between (0, 0) and (x-1, y-1) is added twice. Thus, the correct integral is given by subtracting I(x-1, y-1).